# How do I customise my Atom feed?

Tags: zend-framework2, atom-feed, writer

I am creating a new module for my ZF2 application.  I need to expose some data as an Atom feed.  The spec I have been given looks something like this.

```xml
<entry>
    <source>MySource</source>
    <title>MyTitle</title>
    <link href="http://mylink:1" rel="self" />
    <updated>2014-06-17T07:56:03.1696831Z</updated>
    <content type="MyContentType">
        <customerids xmlns="">MAGENTO:1</customerids>
        <customerids xmlns="">CRM:123</customerids>
        <customerids xmlns="">OTHER:999</customerids>
        <passwordalgorithm xmlns="">SHA-2</passwordalgorithm>
        <passwordsalt xmlns="">QxLUF1bgIAdeQX</passwordsalt>
    </content>
</entry>
```

I can make a feed quite easily utilising `Zend\Feed\Writer\Feed`

What I can't work out is how to set the type on the content element and how to add my additional elements to the content element.  All I can get is a type of XHTML with string content.

I'm also having trouble working out how to add the "source" element to the entry.

I really do not want to go down the road of manually making this feed using a view.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only have a partial answer to this.

The XHTML content type [appears to be hard-coded into the Atom renderer](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Feed/Writer/Renderer/Entry/Atom.php#L343), so this isn't something you can easily change. Zend Feed Writer has an 'extensions' system, which you may be able to use to achieve what you're after; but this isn't documented and I can't easily see how it works from looking at the code so this probably won't be straightforward.

For setting the source, you should be able to do something like:

```
$source = $entry->createSource();
$source->setTitle('Source title');
// [etc.]
$entry->setSource($source);
```

The component appears to require certain elements on the source element which doesn't quite match the single value example in your question, so this may or may not allow you to do what you're after.

Since your example consists mainly of custom elements, I would question whether Atom is well suited for this task. I probably wouldn't just use a view as you mentioned in your question, but you'll probably have a much easier time using either DomDocument or SimpleXML directly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  The atom renderer in the framework is too rigid for my needs.  It seems like it is specifically made for a feed of content, blog posts for example.

As Tim mentioned, the more flexamle approach for such a customised feed it to use DomDocument or SimpleXML directly rather than the rendered which abstracts away that detail.

And that is exactly what I have done and this has enabled me to create the feed that was specified.

Thanks for the confirmation, Tim.